# Yahoo Oauth Redirect Errors

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am trying to implement oath using Yahoo's api with php. When I attempt to get authorization, a Yahoo page loads asking me to login to give authorization. That page has some weird characters, and when I enter an email address and click "Next", it gives an error about a timeout:
[image: image of login page]

I don't do a lot of web programming and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
$client_id = "dj0y........";
$client_secret = "23f......";
$redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com/yweather.html";
getSslPage("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&response_type=code&language=en-us");
```

and

```
public function getSslPage($url, $optional_headers=null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $headers = array("User-Agent: ISCADG/v1.0 (http://www.example.com; john@example.com)");
    if ($optional_headers) {
        $headers = array_merge($headers, $optional_headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to iframe it? Most of the oAuth thingies i have worked with dont like that. Try to provide a redirect url and actually redirecting to yahoos domain for authorization and let them return back to you

Comment: This is incorrect `$redirect_uri = "http://www.example.com/yweather.html";`. The redirect_uri is a callback to your website.

Comment: @OscarSortlandKolsrud I am not using iframe. Just a simple web page to test with.

Comment: @JohnHanley I do have our domain in the real code. I just used example.com for SO. Sorry for the confusion.